# Is there any reduced clause in "I'm not the person helped"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, passive-voice, active-vs-passive

Firstly, I thought it work same way with:

> I'm not the person who helped.

But someone told me "It's wrong, "*I'm not the person helped*" is passive.

What is the difference between the two? Where is the reduced clause in the sentence written on title? What is the thing which makes the sentence on title passive?

Comment: **I'm not the person who helped** = Help was given to someone, but not by me. **I'm not the person [who was] helped** = Someone received help, but it was not me. **The person helped** is the reduced clause.

Comment: Thank you, but how **was** omitted in this sentence? In fact I can understand most of these reduced clause sentences. But that omited of "was" looks weird. Is there any specific topic about that?

Comment: In "I'm not the person helped", it's just "helped" that is a so-called 'reduced' relative clause. "The person helped" is not a clause, but a noun phrase. Please see my answer.

Comment: @KateBunting do you think If I would have written **"I didn't get helped"** would it be passive voice?

Comment: @user123960 I'll jump in here and say that "I didn't get helped" is a passive voice.

Answer (score 4):

> [1] *I'm not the person* [*helped*].

In [1], "helped" is a so-called 'reduced' relative clause modifying the nominal "person" in the noun phrase "the person helped". The unreduced, and much more likely, counterpart is *I'm not the person* [*who was helped*]. Past-participial clauses as modifiers in NP structure have a passive interpretation, as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase in internal complement function: *I'm not the person helped by Ed.*

> [2] *I'm not the person* [*who helped*].

[2] has a different structure and a different meaning. Again the bracketed element, "who helped", is modifying the head noun "person", but it is an active relative clause, not a passive one, as evident from the admissibility of a direct object: *I'm not the person who helped Ed*

Note that not everyone accepts the term 'reduced relative clause'. They prefer to call the bracketed clause in [1] simply a past-participial clause

Comment: I always hear sentences like in 1. But the second one, regardless of meaning, looks like stressed or emphasized. Right?

Comment: @user123960 Yes, it's quite likely that the negative component would be stressed.

Comment: @BillJ how did you work out that the unreduced clause was "who was helped", and not, let's say, "who has been helped" (or any similar context-fitting tense)? Or does it not depend on context?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not the person helped.

seems to be a shortens form of

> I'm not the person who was helped.

or something like

> I'm not the person Jane helped.

Thus "the person helped" is the reduced clause.

The omission of the relative pronoun "who" could be said to reduce the clause "who was helped". But "Jane helped" is itself a reduced version of "who Jane helped".

The loss of information caused by either of these omissions means that the sentence could be either of these forms unless context makes the meaning clear. Of course, in real dialog, context will usually make this clear.

Technically "*I'm not the person helped*" is in [the passive voice](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/passive-voice/?gclid=CjwKCAiAiKuOBhBQEiwAId_sK-RqFZ3VyUUA_H6bwAmPI4XJ3Il3g59aLF24_uTYqG5OUU_hNmaYrRoCHcUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), because the subject "*the person*" receives the action rather than performing it. But eve the full form "*I'm not the person who Jane helped.*" is technically in the passive voice, although the agent (Jane) is specified.

> I'm not the person who helped.

is a perfectly valid sentence, but it has a quite different meaning. "*the person helped*" is the person who **got** help. "*the person **who** helped*" is the person who **gave** help.

A form such as

> I didn't get helped.

is also technically passive, because the subject "I" receives the action, but is not quite the kind of think people usually mean when they write about the passive voice. But it does obscue the agent, who could be inserted in a "by" clause, such as:

> - I didn't get helped by anyone.
> - I didn't get helped by Jane.

Comment: Omitted "was" looks weird to me. By the way is this sentence passive voice? "**I didn't get helped?**"

Comment: I have added "I didn't get helped" to the answer. I am not sue quite what you mean by *Omitted "was"* as it is "who was" that is (possibly) omtted from the original sentence. Please clarify.

Comment: I meant in "I'm not the person helped?" __who was helped__ hasn't been written. But okay I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @user123960
 reduced clauses and omitted elements are all about things that haven't been written, but are implied. They are often written about as if the full form had been written or at least thought of first, and then cut down. Of course it usually does not happen that way, but that provides a handy way to analyze such constructions.